# Unit record of each type

Tags: sql, sql-server

On SQL Server 2008,I need to select the first distinct occurrence of each person in the following table:

```
ID           WeeklyAvg    MonthlyAvg
1            8            0
1            7            3
2            9            1
2            6            4
2            6            4
.......................
....................
```

The output should be:

```
1       8       0
2       9       1
```

How do I achieve this?
Even better if I can avoid putting all the 'distinct' columns in the group by clause,just because sql server restricts so.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: You've been here for over a year, you should know by now to show *some* sort of code you've tried first.  Secondly, how do you *know* which is the first occurence in the table?  There seems to be no sort order.

Comment: I would not need a sort order as I would not expect distinct to return more than one set for each record type.However,in case there are any outliers,the order would not matter.

Comment: Nonsense; without a sort order, SQL Server is just as likely to return `1, 7, 3` instead of `1, 8, 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the "first" row:

```
SELECT ID, WeeklyAvg, MonthlyAvg
FROM
(
SELECT ID, WeeklyAvg, MonthlyAvg,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RowNum
     FROM {table}
) A
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Note that the "first" row will be arbitrary unless you specify a particular order.

Comment: +1 but please fix the syntax error - `OVER()` needs an `ORDER BY`.